# How can I log in to facebook using python (requests/urllib3)?

Tags: python, http, post, cookies, urllib

Im trying to use http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/ to log into facebook automatically.

```
s = requests.session()
params = {'email':'MYEMAILHERE','pass':'MYPASSHERE'}
r = s.post("https://www.facebook.com/login.php/", params = params)

print r.text
```

But instead of fb showing me the home page it shows the me the "your cookies are disabled"... page.

Comment: FB has an extensive REST API. Is there something you think you can accomplish with this method that can't be done through the API?

Comment: https://github.com/michaelhelmick/requests-facebook

Answer (score 2):

Michael Heimlich made a project for integrating with the Facebook API using python-requests:

https://github.com/michaelhelmick/requests-facebook

Still waiting for the proper REST integration though.

There is also FacePy: https://github.com/jgorset/facepy