# Python3 How would I log in Facebook using requests

Tags: facebook, python-3.x, python-requests

`<input type="text" class="inputtext" name="email" id="email" value="" tabindex="1">` is the email box

`<input type="password" class="inputtext" name="pass" id="pass" tabindex="2">` is the password box

`<input value="Connexion" tabindex="4" type="submit" id="u_0_v">`
is the submit button
Now... I have this script running but I still can't manage to login ( I get to the same login page: facebook.com)

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

body = {'email':'xxxx@hotmail.com','pass':'xxxxx',}
con = requests.post('https://www.facebook.com', data=body)
s = BeautifulSoup(con.content)
print (s)
```

Do I have to pass in the 'submit button' in the body{}. I thought I should include it but there is no name for the submit button so I don't know how to include it in the body{}. Thanks for the help

Comment: @alfasin Do you think you can help me on this one? :)

Comment: did you search stackoverflow and read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11472148/how-can-i-log-in-to-facebook-using-python-requests-urllib3 for example?

Comment: I replied here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31497720/1057429

Comment: @alfasin I see facebook is an exception and in this case a bad example of how you can login a 'formal' website. May we try with this: `<form class="LoginForm" action="https://secure.runescape.com/m=weblogin/login.ws" method="post">`  with  `<input type="text" id="username"  name="username" value="******" tabindex="1">`and  `<input type="password" id="password" " tabindex="2">` having `<input type="submit" value="Log In" name="submit">`. I tried to log in with the action url with the post request but it would bring me to a 404 not found page...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You always need to pay attention to any additional (hidden) fields, that are sent along credentials, and might be needed for any server processing.

That is the case for your example with runescape.com. When you use your browser to intercept data, that is normally being sent along with the form, you can modify the script in this manner:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

body = {'username':'xxxx@hotmail.com','password':'xxxxx','submit':'Login','mod':'www','dest':'community'}
con = requests.post('https://secure.runescape.com/m=weblogin/login.ws', data=body)
s = BeautifulSoup(con.content)
print(s)
```

You can see `mod` and `dest` parameters were needed to make the server processing function. As for the submit button, it is rarely checked for, but it is always safer to include it as well (as I did in this example).

The result is not 404 anymore, but the login will nevertheless fail, as there is Captcha in place to prevent automatic login.

As for Facebook, there are a lot of complicated supplementary fields, that would require a lot of reverse engineering to be done. I would strongly suggest to consider using the official Facebook Graph API (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api) if possible to accomplish what you need.

Comment: Your answer matchs perfectly with my question but I still have 2 questions with what you just wrote. First, if I have to use the submit button in the body{} but  the submit button doesn't have a 'name=Submit_button' but have 'id=submit_it' and 'value='submit_me'...How should I place the submit in the body?  Secondly, is there a way for.. when you are at the Captcha page, send the image to the user so he can manually answer the captcha? (Meanwhile, the requests would wait for the user to write an answer to the Captcha) Thank you very much for your time and your answer :)

Comment: Hey! I just tried your script and it brang me to the same 404 page (not found) any idea why? I didn't work so I can't click the answered button :S

Comment: No idea why it wouldn't work, mine works okay exactly as posted: https://gist.github.com/jendagroovy/dccf5375905b9255b002

Comment: As for captcha, yes in principle that should be possible. You first have to navigate to the login form url, parse the document, find captcha and send its url to user. But you also have to pay attention to any additional hidden fields in the form, remember their values and use them in the following login request

Comment: As for submit button without `name` attribute - such field is not sent with the form, so you need not to worry about it.

Comment: I have no idea why but I tried running the script today and it worked somehow... without captcha or anything (prob since I had a good user/password combination) but I don't understand your answer for the captcha... I should print the url with the captcha in it so I can open up my browser and manually solve it?

Comment: Yes you take the image URL from the source, but you also need to save additional hidden fields, as there probably will be some catpcha ID, which the server needs to match the image with the correct answer. Maybe try to search here on SO for questions about scrapping with catpcha.

Comment: you are a genious... I didn't think about that one! listen I am really greatful for the time you took to help me and I have a few other questions, do you wish to contact me privatly to answer some questions about web scrapping (requests)? I will pay your for the time you took to help me :)